# ASP.net equivalent of ASP's rs.getRows()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, arrays

In classic ASP, you can dump a recordset into an array using getRows().  This is a lot faster way of looping results, and frees up the recordset earlier.

Is there an equivalent in ASP.net (c#?).  I've had a look on google and all I can find is a bunch of ugly while loops that dump the rows in an array list, is there a nicer way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using DataSets or DataReaders or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ADO.Net, the dataset is a disconnected, in-memory representation of data, so you don't need this step.

Answer (score 1):

As RedFilter said, ADO.Net (so Asp.Net) can work disconnected scenario.
I think DataAdapter and Datatable is best match for you.
For example

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION_STRING");
conn.Open;

SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * from Table";

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
DataTable table = new DataTable();

da.Fill(table); // Here is equivalent with getRows()
```

So you fetched all your data to table variable. You can bind this object to a control or you can manipulate the data manually.